# Infinite Scroll not working in own theme

Tags: theme-development, plugin-jetpack

I'm developing my own theme and added this in a function which is called with the hook `after_setup_theme` to support infinite scroll:

```
add_theme_support( 'infinite-scroll', array(
    'container'  => 'content',
    'footer' => false,
    'wrapper' => false
) );
```

I got this from http://jetpack.me/support/infinite-scroll/. `content` is the id of the container the new posts should go in. `footer` is set to false since I don't want another footer to be added. `wrapper` is set to false because I don't need a div wrapper.

When I go to my webpage and scroll to the bottom, there is a loading anymation, but there are no posts loaded (there are more posts though). I see that there is a javascript error:

```
TypeError: infiniteScroll.scroller is undefined at infinity.js:485
```

I also see there is an ajax request when I scroll to the bottom, but that page returns:

```
{"type":"empty"}
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I get this working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need either a `content.php` or `content-<post format>.php` OR use a render:

```
add_theme_support( 'infinite-scroll', array(
    'container'  => 'content',
    'footer' => false,
    'render' => 'render_function',
    'wrapper' => false
) );

function render_function() {
    get_template_part('loop');
}
```

This implies you have a `loop.php`.

Comment: Would be nice if you linked to the relevant documentation... What does the `render` argument is about? ::::::::: I also saw the 500 error @Otto mentioned, was it related?

Comment: No it wasn't, my question was about the code I listed and not about the code on my blog. I got this from [the earlier mentioned link](http://jetpack.me/support/infinite-scroll/) in which I took a deeper dive.

Comment: The Answer is for the general public, even if the link is on the Q or here in the Comments, having it in the A itself makes it more complete... but up to you...

Comment: I had assumed you had read my tutorial on this from the start, creating a content.php and adjusting your main Loop is the first step: http://ottopress.com/2012/jetpack-and-the-infinite-scroll/ . And your code above is wrong, you don't need a render function, and calling loop.php from it is incorrect anyway.

Comment: Well it works. I don't say you have to use this, I just say this is a working solution. Also, you never linked to your tutorial before, so _why on earth_ assume I read it!?

Comment: Well, I assumed you had read it because it's like the second or third result on Google when you search for "jetpack infinite scroll".

Comment: Still would've been better if you just linked to it.

Comment: Camil, @Otto already told you where to find it. A _Thank you_ isn't too much and a much better use of your time instead of complaining about it. He gave you an answer (for free), told you where to find it and you're using more energy to complain about it not being served on a silver tablet than to just open a new tab and type those _three_ words. Sorry, but this is an #epicfail.

Comment: I'm sorry, but Otto (or his website) in no way helped me get the answer. In fact, he was talking about the code on my blog a significant time while that was an other code.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely, your theme is missing either the `wp_head()` call in the header.php (add it right before the `</head>`), or the `wp_footer()` call in the footer.php (add it right before the `</body>`).

Comment: Thanks. My `wp_footer()` was called after the `</html>` so I changed that, but it still doesn't work. The `wp_head()` is located well.

Comment: Took a look at your blog, and your site is throwing 500 errors when the infinite scroll is called. This is likely an .htaccess or other server configuration problem. Try disabling plugins that might be interfering, and if you have anything strange in your config, try removing those.

Comment: That's because I'm still developing. My question is about the code listed, the code on my website isn't always the same. But I deactivated all plugins (except Jetpack) and it still didn't work. I never touched my `wp-config.php`. Same story for the `.htaccess`.

Comment: Have you called infinity.js in your wp-head or in functions ? And did you check it properly ?